# Latitude out of bounds

Tags: sql-server, geography, sqlgeography

I get following exception when using Entity Framework to get data from bounds from a google map:

**FormatException: 24201:** Latitude values must be between -90 and 90 degrees.

```
POLYGON((81.9882716924738 140.187434563007,21.5587046599696 140.187434563007,21.5587046599696 -40.1641279369925,81.9882716924738 -40.1641279369925,81.9882716924738 140.187434563007))
```

I can see other have same problem, but havent found anything that solves this. I would expect that first coordinate for point is the latitude and second for longitude? And none is above 90 so why do I get this error? I tried swapping lat and lng but with same problem.

This is the failing line:

```
var poly = FindByBoundingBox(northEastLat, northEastLng, southWestLat, southWestLng);
DbGeography polygon = DbGeography.FromText(poly, 4326); 

var parksWithinPolygon = dbCtx.SiteList.Where(p => 
    p.PolygonCenter.Intersects(polygon)).Select(p=>p.SiteName).ToList();
```

As Damien states first problem is that Sql server expects longitude first and then lattitude. This throws another error, redirecting to another problem:

"This operation cannot be completed because the instance is not valid".

My best bet is it's the they way/order I build the polygon. Has anyone succeeded in mapping google bounds to a polygon in SQL server? In short I am trying to get any data (data has a point column) within the google map bounds.

The function to calculate polygon is listed below:

```
public string FindByBoundingBox(double northEastLat, double northEastLng, double southWestLat, double southWestLng)
{   //Create poylgon of bounding box 
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo customCulture = (System.Globalization.CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
    customCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";

    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = customCulture;
    var bboxWKT = string.Format("POLYGON(({1} {0},{1} {2},{3} {2},{3} {0},{1} {0}))", northEastLat, northEastLng, southWestLat, southWestLng);

    return bboxWKT;
}
```

Comment: "I tried swapping lat and lng but with same problem" - but that should have fixed it. SQL `GEOGRAPHY` WKT representation uses `long lat` not `lat long`.

Comment: I tried doing that but then I get: This operation cannot be completed because the instance is not valid. Use MakeValid to convert the instance to a valid instance. Note that MakeValid may cause the points of a geometry instance to shift slightly.

Comment: POLYGON((180 89.8489730732467,180 -80.2507546123243,-180 -80.2507546123243,-180 89.8489730732467,180 89.8489730732467))

Comment: So, learn to distinguish that when you get a *completely different message*, it's not the **same** problem. Please [edit] your question to include this type of information.

Comment: Thanks, your right. I have updated question.

Comment: What is the problem, where is the error coming from now? The code above works fine if you use the POLYGON from the comment above.

Comment: The search dosent provide the data needed and if I keep zooming out it gives following error: "This operation cannot be completed because the instance is not valid. Use MakeValid to convert the instance to a valid instance. Note that MakeValid may cause the points of a geometry instance to shift slightly".

Comment: Bear in mind, also, that polygons on a globe don't separate the surface into an *inside* and an *outside*. It separates the globe into two separate regions but neither is "inside" or "outside" the other. It's likely that your other error is in constructing a polygon that is "every part of the globe other than this small rectangle" when you intended "this small rectangle". You need to use the left-hand rule here.

Comment: I read another thread also mentioning the left hand rule but I havent figured out what it actually means. What will be the order of the point in the polygon when you have a northEast.Lat/Lng and southWest.Lat/Long? I guess it is possible to query the database from google bounds or have I chosen a wrong strategy?

Answer (score 0):

OK i figured it out. As Damien stated the order of coordinates is oppesite of google. In SQL long needs to be first. Next thing is what is the "left hand rule". You need to create your polygon starting from lower left corner and then counter clock wise.